# Securing a backyard animal / cat shelter fence from escape?

Tags: fence

I need to secure some pets, namely a few kitties, from escaping an enclosed area. My thought is to use some form of standoffs that can attach to the wire fence in order to attach a top arch of lightweight chicken wire fencing. Here is the current fence:

[image: fence example]

Everything I've seen so far needs either a wood fence or a substantial stake. Example:
[image: fence standoffs]

Are there any forms of standoffs available, or buildable, that would work on a wire fence with these less substantial metal stakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any fence that will even stand a chance of keeping a cat in needs to be like 8 feet high. Depending on how adventurous they are, they'll just jump on top of the arch.

And if they're declawed you shouldn't be letting them outside unsupervised anyway.

But w/e... buy **more metal posts**, bend them at a 45, 1/3 of the way up, and attach that third (<strike>as elsewhere</strike> with something better than plastic zip ties) to the existing posts. Make sure you get the homeowner version and not the industrial, or you won't be able to bend it.

Comment: That's a very good idea. Any thoughts on precisely the best posts to buy and the process for bending them?  The posts that I have in there now are not very conducive to bending, so I'd suspect I would need to get some entirely round ones that can have a curve bent at the point where you want to bend over... Really appreciate your thoughts here!

Comment: @ylluminate - Bending them is not going to be easy. Stick them in a vice if you have one mounted, or in an un-capped ~2" pipe that's sticking out of the ground somewhere. Or go behind the store and find their dumpster; stick it in the handle on the side. The thinner (the cheaper) the better. I've seen some that are ~3/8" thick (no joy), and others more like 1/8". If you have trouble bending it, find someone who weighs more than you... If the ground is hard enough and they're flimsy enough, just drive it in and push it over. Put those fins on the bottom 1/3 or it will look like a landing area.

Comment: Buy one and see if you can bend it w/o cracking it in half. It should become obvious right away if it's going to work with what they've got at the store. Just be careful not to spear yourself trying to bend it.

Comment: Just go down to your local maker space and borrow a Hossfield bender.  Watch Jurassic Park for ideas of what kinds of signs you should put on the fence.